# Magento - 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax Error

Tags: sql, magento

I get quite a few of the below errors in my Magento exception log.  Does anyone know how I would go about fixing this?

```
2011-12-10T22:13:41+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(375): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Newcustom.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Newcustom.php(145): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Newcustom->_getProductCollection()
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Newcustom->_beforeToHtml()
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(191): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(134): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(502): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('<h3>New Watches...')
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('<h3>New Watches...')
#17 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Cms_Block_Block->_toHtml()
#18 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#20 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('right', true)
#22 /home/mysite/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/twistedtime/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(56): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('right')
#23 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(469): include('/home/mysite/...')
#24 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(531): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#25 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(559): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#26 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#29 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(147): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#30 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(27, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#31 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#32 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#33 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#35 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#36 /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#37 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#38 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check filters in your _getProductCollection function. If you don't have any then check init methods of all custom models you have.